# How can I disable a specific input field form bootstrap 5 validation script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I will try to make it short as possible. I have built a signup form for my project using bootstrap 5 validators and I'm facing a problem with the retype password input, if the user writes a password that didn't match the password he wrote earlier the green border of the input keep showing and the red border not showing not red and the jquery script of password comparison is actually working. here is my code I hope you understood my issue :

```
       <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-signup" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-signup-tab">
          
          <form class="row row m-auto p-5 g-2 needs-validation" method="post" action="../public/include/signup.inc.php" id="reg-form" novalidate>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Fname" minlength="3" maxlength="12" placeholder="First Name..." onclick="validate()" autofocus required>
                <div class="valid-feedback" id="fnvt">
                  Looks good !
                </div>
                <div class="invalid-feedback" id="fnvf">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="LName" placeholder="Last Name..." required>
                <div class="valid-feedback" id="lnvt">
                  Looks good!
                </div>
                <div class="invalid-feedback" id="lnvf">

                </div>
              </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter your email..." required>
              <div class="valid-feedback" id="emvt">
                Looks good!
              </div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback" id="emvf">Email not correct !</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="password" class="form-control no-validate" name="pw1" minlength="6" maxlength="24" id="pw1" placeholder="Enter a password..." required >
              <div class="valid-feedback" id="pwvt1">
                Looks good!
              </div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback" id="pwvf1">Enter a password !</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pw2" id="pw2" placeholder="Retype your password..." minlength="6" required>
              <div class="valid-feedback" id="cpvt"></div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback" id="cpvf">Password not match</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="tel" value="05"  maxlength="10" minlength="10" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" placeholder="Phone number..." class="form-control" id="phone" onkeypress="validate(event)" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Write a correct phone number.
              </div>
              <div class="valid-feedback">
              </div>
            <div class="col-15 mt-3">
              <div class="form-check form-switch">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
                <label class="form-check-label" style="font-family: Tajawal; color: #fff;" for="invalidCheck">
                  By signing up, I agree to the terms and coniditons of the platform !
                </label>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  You must agree before submitting.
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="justify-content-center mt-4" action="?" method="POST">
                <div class="mt-2 g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key">
                  <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                </div>
                <br/>
            <div class="col-12 mt-3">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submitup" type="submit">Register</button>
            </div>
              </div>
          </form>
```

Bootstrap 5 validation script :

```
  'use strict'

  
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
})()
```

jquery password compare :

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  
  $("#reg-form").submit(function(event){
  let $pw1 = $("#pw1");
  let $pw2 = $("#pw2");
  let $error = $("#cpvf");
  let $true = $("#cpvt");
  if ($pw1.val() === $pw2.val()) {
    return true;
  }if ($pw1.val() !== $pw2.val()) {
    $error.text("Password not Match");
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
})
```

[here is an example of the problem, the code is working but the retype border is green and it is supposed to show a red border.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OtVk.png)

best regards.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54118272/bootstrapvalidator-disable-specific-validation-for-given-field

Comment: Check your HTML first.